# Can I use a pandera DataFrameModel to validate a property involving multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, pandera

I have the feeling that pandara's checks are primarily designed to run on a single dataframe. Assume I have a code which loads data into two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. For example, after having loaded `df1`, I want to load `df2` and validate that all values in the column `df2.col2` are member of `df1.col1`. This seems to require that we define the check dynamically at runtime. Is this possible with pandera?

**EDIT**
There is a solution if we convert the DataFrameModel of `df2` to a schema:

```py
import pandera as pa
import pandas as pd

class MyModel(pa.DataFrameModel):
    col2: pa.typing.Series[int] = pa.Field(ge=0)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,2]})

col1_values = df1.col1.unique()

UpdatedSchema = MyModel.to_schema().update_column('col2',
                checks=[pa.Check.isin(col1_values)])

#the validation works
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2':[1,2,1]})
df2 = UpdatedSchema(df2)

#the validation fails
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2':[1,2,3]})
df2 = UpdatedSchema(df2) #this works
```

But I wonder if there is a way to do the same without requiring to convert to a `DataFrameSchema` ?

Comment: If you are referring to `Pandas` when writing pandera then:
You need to `merge` the two dataframes on a common key and then compare the two columns now in the same dataframe

Comment: For more help you need to post sample of the two dataframes and expected output

Comment: No, I was refering to Pandera (https://pandera.readthedocs.io).

Comment: I have found a solution (see edit), but this involves a Schema, this is not the object-oriented API with a DataFrameModel. So I leave this question open.